# Use defines in Build Artifact name Cube Ide

Tags: c++, stm32, stm32cubeide

I'm trying to use my code defines:

```
#define SW_MAJ 0
#define SW_MIN 3
```

in the output name of the Build Artifact (like `"Name_v${SW_MAJ}.${SW_MIN}"`).
I know one can use Build Variables to save 0 i.e. 3 as a string to be used in the name, but the existence in code is important.

So I'm looking for a solution to either use code defines in Artifact Name or String Build Variable as int in code.